# Why won't this jquery resize code work only chrome?

Tags: jquery, css

Bit of a strange one. For some reason this code works fine in all browsers apart from Google Chrome. In Chrome, when I resize the browser the code doesn't execute unless its like above 860 or something.

What's even more weird is that when I use the inspect tool, it works just fine...
It's only when I have the browser open as normal that it doesn't work.

Any suggestions of why this could be?

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 819){
        $(".hamburger-menu").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
```

Comment: the `resize` wont trigger on page load. U need to execute the code on `$(document).ready()` too

Comment: I did already have that above the function. It's just strange why its only chrome where it doesn't work as intended

Answer (score 3):

> It's only when I have the browser open as normal that it doesn't work.

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you want to to have the menu toggle on page load, you should use the `$(document).ready()` listener, so your browser always knows to check the width rather than simply wait for a resize event after page loads.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   setMenuDisplay()

   $(window).resize(()=> setMenuDisplay())

   function setMenuDisplay() {
     let display = "block"
     if ($(window).width() > 819) display = "none"
    $(".hamburger-menu").css("display", display);

   } 
 }
```

Even better, use CSS media queries to achieve the same exact thing with less code:

```css
.hamburger-menu {
  display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 820px) {
  .hamburger-menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Definitely use CSS solutions when you can (and where applicable).